# to print values of an array after extracting the array in php

Tags: php

Please help in code that i am unable to print values of associative array after extracting itself

```
class display{
protected $variables = array();
function set($name,$value) {
        $this->variables[$name] = $value;
        }
function render(){                
extract($this->variables);
 // ?? to print values of $variable array
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach($this->variables as $key => $value) {
  echo "{$key}: {$value}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And how do you try to print the values? The array itself (it's `$varables`, not `$variable`, btw) should not be affected.

**Update:** For what I can tell by your reply to the other answer, you do not really need to `extract` array. `extract` jusst puts the variables into local namespace where they will be harder to enumerate. What you need is to use array as is.

```
foreach($this->variables as $k => $v) echo "$k: $v\n";
```

or whatever you want to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using classes, u will need to have something like 
var $variables = array(); or 
public $variables = array();

and if you are using structured , you will need to do 
global $variables;
inside the function .. but as u are using $this-> it indicates ur using a class. You will have to put in some more code in here to make the situation clear.

Comment: Thanks for giving information , and i am giving exact situation in coding 
class dispaly{
 protected $variables = array()
 function set($name,$value) {
        $this->variables[$name] = $value;
        }
 function render(){
  extract($this->variable);
  // here i want to print values of $variable array
 }
}

Please help me really i am strucking with this..

Comment: extract($this->variable); should be extract($this->variables);

Comment: so from what i understand:
$this->variables['k1'] = 'hello';
$this->variables['k2'] = 'world';

extract($this->variables);
echo $k1; /// prints hello
echo $k2; /// prints world

is that not happening?